# awk less than or equal does't work

Tags: awk, gawk

tmp.log :

```
[2016-12-01 00:00:01] ... 
[2016-12-01 00:00:02] .... 
[2016-12-01 00:00:03] ..... 
[2016-12-01 00:00:04] ......
```

command :

```
awk '$0>="[2016-12-01 00:00:01]" && $0<="[2016-12-01 00:00:03]"' tmp.log
```

output :

```
[2016-12-01 00:00:01] ...
[2016-12-01 00:00:02] ....
```

expected :

```
[2016-12-01 00:00:01] ...
[2016-12-01 00:00:02] ....
[2016-12-01 00:00:03] .....
```

Why the "<=" doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $0 is your whole record, and in the third line it is "[2016-12-01 00:00:03] .....", which is more than "[2016-12-01 00:00:03]".

Comment: so it is like comparing `[2]<=[3]`. It is a string comparison, far from what the OP would want.

Comment: so use $1 instead of $0 assuming FS is the default (space, tab) like here :-)

Comment: @fedorqui - it is comparing  "[2016-12-01 00:00:03] ....." <= "[2016-12-01 00:00:03]" . The latter is a prefix of the former, so the inequality does not obey.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu - wrong.  $1 would be "[2016-12-01" in all records.

Comment: @fedorqui string compare is an option here due to date format used in the sample even if you are totaly right on the concept. An heavier option is to use the mktime to convert in epoch value before

Comment: @NeronLeVelu yes, I know awk compares dates. The thing, though, is that it is not _just_ a string with a date, since it contains other things (`[` and `]`). The solution should be to strip those and compare the "clean" dates.

Comment: @user31264 , oops sorry, you are right, need `$1 " " $2`

Comment: @NeronLeVelu - yes, either that or $1 "]" with field separator "]".